# XSLT 2.0: Remove xmlns attribute

Tags: xml, excel, xslt

I have a problem where Microsoft Excel wants a specific format for inline formatted text such that the Data element has a xmlns of "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" but the child elements (Font and B) have no defined namespace:

```
<Cell>
  <ss:Data xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" ss:Type="String" xml:space="preserve">
    <Font>normal text</Font>
    <B>bold text</B>
    <Font Color="#FF0000">red text</Font>
  </ss:Data>
</Cell>
```

If any xmlns attribute is added to Font or B, they are not rendered correctly in Microsoft Excel.

I have the following source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
    <text>normal text</text>
    <b>bold text</b>
    <red>red text</red>
</document>
```

My XSLT file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="2.0" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">

    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="utf-8" version="1.0"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="'&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-8&quot;?>'"/>

        <xsl:processing-instruction name="mso-application">progid="Excel.Sheet"</xsl:processing-instruction>

        <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
        xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
        xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
        xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
        xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

            <Worksheet ss:Name="Worksheet">
                <Table>
                    <Row>
                        <Cell>
                            <ss:Data xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" ss:Type="String" xml:space="preserve"><xsl:apply-templates select="node()" /></ss:Data>
                        </Cell>
                    </Row>
                </Table>
            </Worksheet>
        </Workbook>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text">
        <Font><xsl:value-of select="." /></Font>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="b">
        <B><xsl:value-of select="." /></B>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="red">
        <Font Color="#FF0000"><xsl:value-of select="." /></Font>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I **want** to achieve the following output (note that the Font and B) elements have no xmlns attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>

<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <Worksheet ss:Name="Worksheet">
        <Table>
            <Row>
                <Cell>
                    <ss:Data xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" ss:Type="String" xml:space="preserve"><Font>normal text</Font><B>bold text</B><Font Color="#FF0000">red text</Font>    </ss:Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
        </Table>
    </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Instead, my XSLT transform gives me (note that xmlns has been added to Font and B elements):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>

<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:kc="http://www.kelvinconnect.com/"
xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <Worksheet ss:Name="Worksheet">
        <Table>
            <Row>
                <Cell>
                    <ss:Data xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" ss:Type="String" xml:space="preserve"><Font xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">normal text</Font><B xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">bold text</B><Font Color="#FF0000" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">red text</Font></ss:Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
        </Table>
    </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

I understand that the defined default namespace (urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet) is being added to the Font and B elements to clarify the namespace, given that the parent item (ss:Data) is defined to be in the "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" namespace, but my problem is that Microsoft Excel simply does not work unless the ss:Data element is defined to use xmlns of "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" AND the B and Font elements do NOT specify an xmlns attribute.

Can anyone suggest a way to alter my XSLT transform such that xmlns elements are not added to B and Font elements?

I tried adding exclude-result-prefixes="#default", but that had no effect.

I have also tried changing my templates to:

```
<xsl:template match="b">
  <xsl:element name="B" namespace="">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

But this merely changed the xmlns attribute to blank (xmlns="") rather than removing the attribute completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the namespace to "" doesn't work because this means the **B** element no longer belongs to any namespace, when you really want it to belong to the `http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40` namespace.

Try doing this instead.

```
<xsl:template match="b">
  <xsl:element name="B" namespace="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Doing it this, means for the "red" you would have to add the attribute like this

```
<xsl:template match="red">
  <xsl:element name="font" namespace="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <xsl:attribute name="Color">#FF0000</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```